# synchronous call from client to server and asynchronous calls between microservices

Tags: client-server, message-queue, synchronous

I am a bit overwhelmed with discussions about whether to use a RMQ/Kafka/Http etc for communication between micro-services. I was hoping to get some insight regarding this. First, my client is a mobile application which makes a synchronous call and awaits a response.

Intuitively, I would not want the internal communication between java server and Python classifier to be synchronous since I'd like to have a high throughput given I could have thousands or millions (hopefully) of clients sending requests simultaneously.

How can I make a non-blocking request-response and also retrieve the request to the same client?

client <-http--> java <--?--> Python

Comment: How about gRPC?

Answer (score 0):

From the question you have posted what comes to my mind is, maybe you can add a layer of cache in between. This cache will have some data preloaded (Depending upon size of memory you can afford) immediately after the application starts. You can have a time bound cache or LRU (Depending upon your architecture). Redis provides simple and efficient way to do this. Here only time wasted would be network latency.
Note:I am new to this platform and in initial stages of answering. So any improvement suggested will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you aiming for non-blocking scaled solution, I recommend using Kafka as a middle layer between the server and the clients.
In this way, the clients sends sync requests to kafka and waits for the server to respond.
Meanwhile the server runs multithreaded system of consumers which polling (i.e consuming) user requests and sending responses to the clients.

So, lets say client Bob sent a request, it queued in a dedicated kafka topic with millions of other user requests waited to be responded.
The server, deals with all the requests under heavy load, eventually gets to Bob's event and finaly sends a response after 5 seconds, now Bob received the response and may close his "session" for that request (there is no actual session like HTTP, but some other compressed/ encoded format you choose).
There are security measures you should consider when choosing the event's format and the detailed communication manner, lets leave this discussion for later since your question is more basic.